# I need to get only updated data from on-promise database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to get only updated data from on-promise database. Because on-promise database updates weekly. If I set up a scheduler with Azure Data Factory, would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at creating an integration run time with a linked service, have a look at the link, there is also change tracking you can setup  [Incrementally load data from a source data store to a destination data store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal)

Answer (score -1):

Azure Data Factory supports scheduler feature, you could create a Schedule Trigger and would help.
Here is the link to follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger